# C++ Passing std::function object to variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I want to pass a callable (`std::function` object) into a class `Foo`. The callable refers to a member method of another class which has arbitrary arguments, hence the `Foo` must be a variadic template. Consider this code:

```
struct Bar {
  void MemberFunction(int x) {}
};

template<typename ...Args>
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)> f) {}
};

int main() {
  Foo<int> m1(&Bar::MemberFunction);
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine. Now I want to write a factory function `MakeFoo()` which returns a `unique_ptr` to a `Foo` object:

```
template<typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args...>> MakeFoo(std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)> f) {
  return std::make_unique<Foo<Args...>>(f);
}
```

Using this function by calling

```
auto m2 = MakeFoo<int>(&Bar::MemberFunction);
```

in main, gives me the following compiler errors:

```
functional.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
functional.cc:21:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘MakeFoo(void (Bar::*)(int))’
       auto m2 = MakeFoo<int>(&Bar::MemberFunction);
                                                  ^
functional.cc:15:35: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args ...> > MakeFoo(std::function<void(Bar*, Args ...)>)
     std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args...>> MakeFoo(std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)> f) {
                                   ^
functional.cc:15:35: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
functional.cc:21:50: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<void(Bar*, Args ...)>’ and ‘void (Bar::*)(int)’
       auto m2 = MakeFoo<int>(&Bar::MemberFunction);
```

It seems to me, that when I call the constructor of `Foo`, the compiler happily converts the function pointer `&Bar::MemberFunction` to a `std::function` object. But when I pass *the same* argument to the factory function, it complains. Moreover, this problem only seems to occur, when `Foo` and `MakeFoo` are variadic templates. For a fixed number of template parameters it works fine.

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Looks like it's still trying to do deduction for `Args` (i.e., you specify the first and it figures out the rest).

Comment: `make_unique` is from C++14, so you're probably using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @RustyX both latest gcc and clang have troubles with it

Comment: I noticed it starts compiling in Clang when I force non-deduction for `Args` in the `std::function` instantiation.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like both gcc and clang think that you didn't specify all of the template arguments for `MakeFoo`. You have given it an `int`, but there's still the rest of the pack to be deduced. And it's non-deducible. (I know you want it to be empty).

Comment: Here's a weird workaround: `template <class T> T id(T t){return t;}` Now `id(MakeFoo<int>)(&Bar::MemberFunction)` works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why doesn't it work without explicit `<int>`?

Prior to C++17, template type deduction is pure pattern matching.

`std::function<void(Foo*)>` can *store* a member function pointer of type `void(Foo::*)()`, but a `void(Foo::*)()` is not a `std::function` of any kind.

`MakeFoo` takes its argument, and pattern matches `std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)>`.  As its argument is not a `std::function`, this pattern matching fails.

In your other case, you had fixed `Args...`, and all it had to do was *convert* to a `std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)>`.  And there is no problem.

What can be converted to is different than what can be deduced.  There are a myriad of types of `std::function` a given member function could be converted to.  For example:

```
struct Foo {
  void set( double );
};
std::function< void(Foo*, int) > hello = &Foo::set;
std::function< void(Foo*, double) > or_this = &Foo::set;
std::function< void(Foo*, char) > why_not_this = &Foo::set;
```

In this case there is ambiguity; in the general case, the set of template arguments that could be used to construct some arbitrary template type from an argument requires inverting a turing-complete computation, which involves solving Halt.

Now, C++17 added deduction guides.  They permit:

```
std::function f = &Foo::set;
```

and `f` deduces the signature for you.

In C++17, deduction doesn't guides don't kick in here; they may elsewhere, or later on.

## Why doesn't it work with explicit `<int>`?

Because it still tries to pattern match and determine what the *rest* of `Args...` are.

If you changed `MakeFoo` to

```
template<class T>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<T>> MakeFoo(std::function<void(Bar*, T)> f) {
  return std::make_unique<Foo<T>>(f);
}
```

suddenly your code compiles.  You pass it `int`, there is no deduction to do, and you win.

But when you have

```
template<class...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args...>> MakeFoo(std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)> f) {
  return std::make_unique<Foo<T>>(f);
}
```

the compiler sees `<int>` and says "ok, so `Args...` starts with `int`.  What comes next?".

And it tries to pattern match.

And it fails.

## How can you fix it?

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T; constexpr tag_t(){}};
template<class T>using block_deduction=typename tag_t<T>::type;

template<class...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args...>> MakeFoo(
  block_deduction<std::function<void(Bar*, Args...)>> f
) {
  return std::make_unique<Foo<T>>(f);
}
```

now I have told the compiler not to deduce using the first argument.

With nothing to deduce, it is satisfied that `Args...` is just `int`, and... [it now works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60a90ecde9a873a2).

Comment: The problem with this reasoning is that when you make the template non-variadic (basically remove `...`), the thing starts working.

Comment: @n.m. agreed; in fact, the problem is not matching std::function per se, the problem is matching the <int,Tail...> pack against the member pointer...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Yep that's basically what I have in a comment to the main post.

Comment: @n.m. [What are you talking about](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6445ea06504318ae)?  Oh, passing in types explicitly.  I get it.

Comment: Just remove all ellipses from the code, don't change anything else, and recompile. How do you explain the results?

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I edited comment -- I missed that the OP was passing `<int>` explicitly.  Answer edited.

Comment: Not that I really understand it, but it solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot deduce the template arguments for `std::function` from a different type, such as member function pointer. Even though a `std::function` can be constructed from on object of that type, to consider the constructor the template arguments of `std::function` must be first known.

To help it deduce, add another overload:

```
template<typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args...>> MakeFoo(void(Bar::*f)(Args...)) {
  return std::make_unique<Foo<Args...>>(f);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice and simple solution, but unfortunately my actual code is a bit more complicated. I also need to be generic about the type of object, on which the member function is called. So the template looks more like `template<typename Obj, typename ...Args>`, where `Obj` can be set to `Bar` or any other class. In this case, I can't really write the argument of `MakeFoo` like this, because it depends on `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MakeFoo<int>( whatever );
```

is equivalent to invoking the hypothetical

```
template<typename ...Tail>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<int,Tail...>> MakeFoo( std::function<void(Bar*,int,Tail...)> f) {
  return std::make_unique<Foo<int,Tail...>>(f);
}
```

clearly, in no way the compiler can deduce that Tail is empty given a `void(Bar::*)(int)`

IMO, the most correct fix ( given the required usage ) is to make the args non deduced:

```
template< typename T >
struct nondeduced { using type = T; };

template<typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<Args...>> MakeFoo( std::function<void(Bar*, typename nondeduced<Args>::type... )> f ) {
```